# how to handle different screen sizes with flutter app

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, flutter-layout

I'm doing an app that can be used on Apple, Android, web and desktop so for many different screen sizes - phone, tablet, laptop, desktop etc.  Is it reasonable to design for say three different layouts - small, medium, and large - where the layout for each could be slightly different  - or is it more common to have just a single basic layout that populates widgets row by row and automatically starts on the next row when a row gets full.

[Edit]
What I mean is that for a large screen I could have one set of widgets and for a small screen I could have a completely different set of widgets - is that reasonable to do or is it too much work. e.g. if the user starts with a large window and then resizes the window to make it small, the appearance and maybe the functionality might change a little bit - is that bad?
This link posted by Kaushik is helpful
[Flutter: How to do responsiveness for "real" mobile/web applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72759067/flutter-how-to-do-responsiveness-for-real-mobile-web-applications/72759118#72759118)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make flutter app responsive according to different screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704497/how-to-make-flutter-app-responsive-according-to-different-screen-size)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72759067/flutter-how-to-do-responsiveness-for-real-mobile-web-applications/72759118#72759118

Comment: What I mean is that for a large screen I could have one set of widgets and for a small screen I could have a completely different set of widgets  - is that reasonable to do or is it too much work.  e.g. if the user starts with a large window and then resizes the window to make it small, the appearance and maybe the functionality might change a little bit  - is that bad?

Answer (score 0):

Using MediaQuery class:

```
mediaSize = MediaQuery.of(context);
```

Then you can get media height and width

```
mediaSize.size.width
mediaSize.size.height
```

If you want to separate different dimensions, equal the above values to another value and divide like math operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
width=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
height=MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

while using width and height use the above code insted of using numericals

```
ex:`Container(
margin:EdgeInsets.only(left:8,right:8),
width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width -20,
height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
)`
```

Here the container have margin of 8 in both left and right and the height will be screen height

Answer (score 0):

Using MediaQuery you can handle the size problem in the app

```
var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
var width = size.width;
var height = size.height;
```